# Numbers $n$ such that $n!$ has all of its exponents odd

Tags: number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

(First paragraph for motivation, second paragraph the actual problem)

I usually have to be on a stand as an embassador for my major (math) for highschoolers, and we usually have problems written on a whiteboard for the kids to try. One of my favorite problems to pose, is whether $50!$ is a square, the idea being that $29$ only appears one time on its prime decomposition (or any prime $26\leq p\leq50$ for that matter). Of course, provided that one knows Bertrand's postulate, this is really easy for arbitrary $n$. But the other day, a kid showed that actually $13$ only appears $3$ times therefore it can't be a prime. So this got me to the following question:

Is there an $n$ relatively big, let's say, greater than $20$ such that all of the exponents of its factorial are odd. In other words, if $n\#$ denotes the product of all the primes less than or equal to $n$, is there an $n$ such that the number

$$\frac{n!}{n\#}$$
is a square?. Since I didn't know what to try I just wrote a very rough python code to check for numbers with that property, and after checking for $n\leq10^5$, the only values are $2,3,4,5$. I didn't want to check more because it took about $20$ minutes to run. I'm very new to programming so I don't doubt the code can be improved, feel free to let me know if you managed to check for bigger $n$. Are these the only ones? And how could I start proving it if so?

Any help is appreciated

My code:

```
from math import log
from time import time
def s(n,p):
   N=int(log(n,p))
   s=0
   for i in range(1,N+1):
       s=s+int(n/(p**i))
   return s
def P(n):
   prime=[True for i in range(n+1)]
   p=2
   while(p*p<=n):
       if(prime[p]==True):
           for i in range(p*p,n+1,p):
               prime[i]=False
       p=p+1
   l=[]
   for p in range(2,n+1):
       if(prime[p]):
           l.append(p)
   return l
n=int(input("Enter a number greater than or equal to 2: ",))
ti=time()
l=[]
for i in range(2,n+1):
   k=0
   for p in P(i):
       if(s(i,p)%2==1):
           k=k+1
   if(k==len(P(i))):
       l.append(i)
tf=time()
print("There are",len(l),"numbers n from 1 to",n,"such that n! has all of its exponents odd, and these are:")
for i in l:
   print(i)
print("This code took",round(tf-ti,2),"seconds to run")
```

Comment: If there is a an odd prime $p$ with  $n/3<p\leq n/2$ then $p$ occurs twice. So this can only possibly be true for finitely many $n.$

Comment: @Dan You are absolutely right, I'll change it

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are absolutely right. I don't know how I missed that. Thank you

Comment: My guess is that the bound $N$ is fairly small, such that, for $x>N$ there is always a prime $p$ with $x<p\leq 3x/2.$ But I don't know much about these extensions to Bertrand.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Just checked it, and according to wikipedia $n=25$ should suffice. It says that theres a prime between $n$ and $n(6/5)$ for $n\geq25$, so that's acually better

Comment: Technically, under your wiki citation, you need $n/3\geq 25.$ The $n$ in the Wikipedia article is different from your $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Once again you're right, but I checked for $n\leq 10^5$, so it's fine

Comment: Wikipedia says that there is always a prime between $3m$ and $4m,$ but presumably that is true for $m>1,$ or the boundary is needed. You can use that to prove there is one between $n/3$ and $n/2,$ by choosing $m=\lfloor n/9\rfloor +1.$ We get  $n/3<3m$ and, for $m$ large, we want $4m<n/2.$ But $$4\lfloor n/9\rfloor+4\leq 4n/9+4=n/2-(n/18-4).$$ So you only need to check up to $18\cdot 4=72.$